# Rigid Body | Copy from active

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I',m struggling with a change from blender 2.79 to 2.8. When you apply a rigid body to something and want to apply it to a lot of other objects, you you use dto (in blender 2.79) go over to your tools panel and hit "copy from active". But now, in blender 2.8, the tools panel no longer exists. Where is the new copy from active setting? The help I've gotten is "object>rigid body>copy from active" but I couldn't find it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the top left of the screen, there is "View", "Select", "Add" and "Object". Select Object, then go down to "rigid body", them "copy from active".

Comment: Thanks! Your da best. HUGE problem now solved thanks to you!